# PHP - send command line output to dynamically named files

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an application which is built in CakePHP 3.

It uses [Console Commands](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/commands.html) to execute several intensive processes in the background using cron.

The application consists of 5 individual commands:

```
src/Command/Stage1Command.php
src/Command/Stage2Command.php
src/Command/Stage3Command.php
src/Command/Stage4Command.php
src/Command/Stage5Command.php
```

These can be executed **manually** by running each one individually, e.g. to execute `Stage1Command.php`:

```
$ php bin/cake.php stage1
```

To make them run via Cron, I created a 6th command (`src/Command/RunAllCommand.php`) which goes through these in order.

```
 // src/Command/RunAllCommand.php
 class RunAllCommand extends Command
 {
     public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
     {
         $stage1 = new Step1Command();
         $this->executeCommand($stage1);

         // ... 

         $stage5 = new Stage5Command();
         $this->executeCommand($stage5);
     }
 }
```

This works fine so I can now execute everything with 1 command, `php bin/cake.php run_all`, which will be added as a cron task to automate running the 5 processes.

The problem I'm having is that each of the 5 commands (`Stage1Command` ... `Stage5Command`) produces output which appears on standard output in the console.

I need to be able to write the output *produced by each of the 5 commands individually* into *dynamically named* files.

So I can't do something like this

```
$ php bin/cake.php run_all > output.log
```

Because

1. `output.log` would contain *everything*, i.e. the output from all 5 commands.
2. `output.log` isn't a dynamic filename, it has been entered manually on the command line (or as the output destination of the cron task).

I looked at [Redirecting PHP output to a text file](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/easiest-way-to-redirect-php-output-to-a-text-file/6614/5) and tried the following.

Added `ob_start();` to `RunAllCommand.php`:

```
namespace App\Command;
ob_start();

class RunAllCommand extends Command { ... }
```

After executing the first task (`Stage1Command`) capturing `ob_get_clean()` to a variable called `$content`:

```
$stage1 = new Step1Command();
$this->executeCommand($stage1);
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

When I `var_dump($content);` it comes out as an empty string:

```
string(0) ""
```

But the output is still produced on the command line when executing `php bin/cake.php run_all` (RunAllCommand.php).

My plan for the dynamic filename was to generate it with PHP inside `RunAllCommand.php`, e.g.

```
// $id is a dynamic ID generated from a database call.
// This $id is being generated inside a foreach() loop so is different on each iteration (hence the dynamic nature of the filename).
$id = 234343; 
$filename_stage1 = 'logs/stage1_' . $id . '.txt'; // e.g. "logs/stage1_234343.txt"
```

Then write `$content` to the above file, e.g.

```
file_put_contents($filename_stage1, $content);
```

So I have 2 problems:

1. The output is being echoed to the console, and unavailable in `$content`.
2. Assuming (1) is fixed, how to "reset" the output buffering such that I can use `file_put_contents` with 5 different filenames to capture the output for the relevant stage.

Comment: May I ask why you a) need to log this into files in the first place, and b) why into separate files? Also, doing `> output.log` would only capture `stdout`, but you do want to log `stderr` too, ie errors, right? Third question, you want both, the regular CLI output as well logging the output to a file? Or do you not want any CLI output, and only log to a file?

Comment: Because, the application we're making performs updates to a database. It's important to be able to understand what's occurred during each stage so it can be reported to a frontend UI. It's much easier to do analysis when you can view the log files for each of the 5 processes individually than having to trawl through 1 file. All of the information is being produced through `$io->out('...')`so seems wrong to have to re-write all that to log it somewhere else, e.g. a database. The processes run for a number of filters which is why the dynamic filename (using `$id` in the question here) is needed.

Comment: with regards to your third question - the process (`RunAllCommand`) is executed via cron. Nobody is sat there looking at the CLI. So it needs to go into files. I'm not bothered whether you can also view it on the CLI or not, the priority is to get the content into the files so they can be viewed in the UI later.

Comment: Can you simply pass the dynamically-generated file name from RunAll to each of the other commands and have them append their output to it?

Answer (score 0):

On each command file you could use the LogTrait then output what file is outputting before any commands to seperate what command is logging or setup the log config with [different scopes](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging-configuration) to output to different files.  example of outputting to the cli-debug.log file.

```
use Cake\Log\LogTrait;

class Stage1Command extends Command
{
    use LogTrait;

    public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
    {
        $this->log('Stage 1 Output: ', 'debug');

        //do stuff

        $this->log('output stage 1 stuff', 'debug');

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you specifying a dynamic filename in that? The linked docs talk about setting up custom logging in the bootstrap file. That won't let me generate the appropriate filename at that point because `RunAllCommand` executes in a loop (in my code `$id` is a dynamic variable that comes from a `foreach` loop).

Comment: The example I showed was something you would place on each command and it would append the log file but output what command it was before any data so you knew what command was outputting.  The custom logging scopes are set in app.php or using the setConfig() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for solving your issue.

#### Option 1 - Using [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

shell_exec returns a string of the output, so you can write it to a log file directly.

```
public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
{
    $stage1_log = shell_exec('bin/cake stage1 arguments');
    file_put_contents('stage1_dynamic_log_file.txt', $stage1_log);

    $stage2_log = shell_exec('bin/cake stage2 arguments');
    file_put_contents('stage2_dynamic_log_file.txt', $stage2_log);
}
```

#### Option 2 - Overwrite the ConsoleOut stream

Alternatively a more CakePHP style would be to call the command slightly differently. If you look at the contents of [executeCommand()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.Console.Command.html#253-282) it does a few checks and then calls `command->run($args, $io)`

Also if you look at how the `ConsoleIo` is constructed, we can override the output method so instead of using `php://stdout` we could use a file instead, if you look at the code for [ConsoleOutput](https://api.cakephp.org/3.8/source-class-Cake.Console.ConsoleOutput.html#155-173) it's just using normal `fopen` and `fwrite`.

```
use Cake\Console\ConsoleIo;
use Cake\Console\ConsoleOutput;

public function execute(Arguments $args, ConsoleIo $io)
{
    // File names
    $id = 234343; 
    $filename_stage1 = 'logs/stage1_' . $id . '.txt';

    // Create command object
    $stage1 = new Stage1Command();

    // Define output as this filename
    $output = new ConsoleOutput($filename_stage1);

    // Create a new ConsoleIo using this new output method
    $stage1_io = new ConsoleIo($output);

    // Execute passing in the ConsoleIo with text file for output
    $this->executeCommand($stage1, ['arguments'], $stage1_io);
}
```